# Two homeomorphic graphs have $n_i$ vertices and $m_i$ edges, show that $m_1-n_1=m_2-n_2$

Tags: graph-theory

> If two homeomorphic graphs ($H_1$ and $H_2$) have $n_i$ vertices and $m_i$ edges, show that $m_1-n_1=m_2-n_2$

I know by the degree summ formula $\sum deg(v)=2E$

Proof:

Contract both graphs to the same graph $G$ with number of points $(k)$. Then, add vertices, such that the resulting graph becomes ($H_1$ and $H_2$).

For each vertex that we add, the number of edges increases by $1$ and the total degree increases by $2$.

Suppose we need to add $s$ points to $G$ to make it $H_1$ and $t$ points to $G$ to make $H_2$.

Then it follows that since $$\sum_{v\in G} deg(v)=2E$$

Since adding $s$ points contributes $2s$ to the total degree, similarly for $t$. I get: $$\sum_{s+v\in G} deg(v)=2E+s$$ Similarly for t:$$\sum_{t+v\in G} deg(v)=2E+t$$

Now I'm left to connect the total degree with the number of vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any graph is homeomorphic to a graph with no vertices of degree $2.$ In the process of removing a vertex of degree $2,$ you lose one vertex and one edge, so the difference $m-n$ is unchanged. Therefore, it suffices to show is that homeomorphic graphs with no vertices of degree $2$ are isomorphic (and so have the same number of vertices and the same number of edges). This is because, in the absence of vertices of degree $2,$ a homeomorphism between two graphs must take vertices to vertices and edges to edges.

Answer (score 1):

The degree sum for the $H_1$ is $\sum_{s+v\in G} deg(v)=2E+2s$ and for $H_2$ is $\sum_{t+v\in H} deg(v)=2E+2t$.
So number of edges are $E+s$ and $E+t$. I guess you can continue now to get the answer.